# Object value received incorrectly while passing complex object to web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http-post, webapi

I'm using ASP .Net Core web API & Angular here. Both the 'code' & 'pageInfo' values are shown **correctly** in the **console**, but when passed to the API, the **String** value is passed **correctly** only, the **object** values are showing **wrong** value (0 and null).

**API-**

```
[HttpPost("get/{code}/{pageInfo}")]
        public IActionResult Get(string code, Model pageInfo)
        {
            var data = _Service.GetData(code, pageInfo);
            if (data != null)
            {
                ---
            }
            else
            {
                ---
            }
        }
```

**Service-**

```
getAllData(code:any,pageInfo:any):Observable<any>{    
    console.log(code, pageInfo);
    const url = `/get/${code}/${pageInfo}`;    
    return this.http.post<any>(url, code, pageInfo);
  }
```

Can anyone help me to find what mistake I've made here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by some modifications-

- Changing parameter sequence
- Using [FromBody]

**API-**

```
[HttpPost("get/{code}/{pageInfo}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] Model pageInfo, string code)
{
    var data = _Service.GetData(pageInfo, code);
    if (data != null)
      {---}
    else
      {---}
}
```

**Service-**

```
getAllData(pageInfo:any, code:any):Observable<any>{    
    const url = `/get/${code}`;    // have passed only the string value via URL
    return this.http.post<any>(url, pageInfo, code);
  }
```